# How can I get list of IAM Roles from EC2 using Java SDK or Amazon API?

Tags: java, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

There are several notes on how to run Instance with given IAM Role and create one. But what about retrieving such data from EC2 service using Amazon Client (Java SDK) or http-requests via Amazon API? Can I get such list of IAM Roles somehow (they were preliminary created in EC2 console by devOps team, so I must somehow expose them in other web-application)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Okay. Seems like AmazonIdentityManagementClient listInstanceProfiles() call does the trick.

Some kind of solution should work. Sorry for bother.

```
public Collection<String> getIAMRolesRange() {
        AmazonIdentityManagementClient identityManagementClient = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccount.getAccessKeyId(), awsAccount.getAccessSecret()));
        ListInstanceProfilesResult listInstanceProfilesResult = identityManagementClient.listInstanceProfiles();
        List<String> iamRoles = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(InstanceProfile instanceProfile: listInstanceProfilesResult.getInstanceProfiles()) {
            iamRoles.addAll(Collections2.transform(instanceProfile.getRoles(), iamRoleToStringFunction));
        }

        return iamRoles;
    }
```